# Is there any (real) Office 2007 look and feel for Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, office-2007, look-and-feel

I'm aware of the Substance look and feels and that they have a Office 2007 look-a-like look and feel. But this look and feel doesn't look like the Office 2007 design at all, the colors are a lot different for example.

Are there other look and feels which mimic the Office 2007 more accurately?

Comment: It may help if you indicated what framework/language you are working with (.Net, C++, MFC, etc). I'm not familiar with theSubstance, so I don't know what it applies to. Sorry!

Comment: Ah, sorry, just noticed the tags for Java/swing. You may want to edit your post to include that in the main text so that others don't make the same mistake I just did :)

Comment: I noticed quite a few people don't specify the domain of their question and instead put some tags that hint at it!! please clearly state in your question that you're talking about the Java framework called Swing (if *that* is what you're talking about)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look!

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1010

Answer (score 4):

I suggest looking at jide software conponents at http://www.jidesoft.com/

Comment: I can only find Office 2003 components

Answer (score 1):

The author of Substance is also developing "Flamingo" which includes a Ribbon component. As far as I understand, Flamingo has no dependency on Substance and uses whatever LAF is installed (so the system LAF should work).

You migh want to give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using the ribbon component. What I need now is an Office 20007 look and feel :)

Answer (score 0):

With the Windows 7/VS2010/.NET4  wave, the ribbon will become a standard component in Win32 and also the .NET framework I think.